# Get value from Hidden Checkbox

Tags: javascript, jquery, checkbox

I have looked high and low, and can't find a solution to this problem. I have a hidden checkbox.  I don't want to show this checkbox, as it is more of an "identifier" as to what type of item was added to a dynamic field.

I use this:

```
<input type="hidden" name="servrecchecked[]" id="servrecchecked" class="servrecchecked" value="checked" />
```

And later, in jquery, I check on a blur of any field in that row, and pull the values from the row.

This works fine:

```
var approved = row.find("#approved").is(':checked') ? "checked" : "no";
```

but it is not hidden.  The hidden one:

```
var servrecchecked = row.find("#servrecchecked").is(':checked') ? "checked" : "no";
```

does not push the value when checked, but I have gotten a "no" value for some that don't meet the checked qualifier.

I can't seem to figure out how to get the value if it is checked, and am asking the braintrust here if there is any way to make that work.

Thanks

Comment: Can you post your row HTML. Also make a simple fiddle in jsfiddle if possible.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The element with the id `servrecchecked` is not a checkbox. You have defined it as a hidden input element.

To check the value of the hidden element you may use

```
var servrecchecked = row.find("#servrecchecked").val() == "checked" ? "checked" : "no";
```

If you store either "checked" or "no" in your hidden element you can just use

```
var servrecchecked = row.find("#servrecchecked").val();
```

In both cases above, you don't need to `find` you can directly look for the element using the id like `$("#servrecchecked").val()`

Comment: Can't believe I missed that.  Dumb rookie mistake.  But unfortunately, I still don't get "checked" value.  I'm not even getting the "no" anymore.

Comment: See [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/keKDD/). See if you have any other rookie mistake.

Comment: I will have several different rows, and all are dynamically generated.  So I need to use `find`, to make sure I get that value from that particular row.  I could have dozens of rows, some or all of which might qualify to be identified with this field.

Comment: duplicate ids are not a good idea. Why don't you just use the class to find elements? i.e. replace `find("#servrecchecked")` with `find(".servrecchecked")`

Comment: I got it.  Another rookie mistake.  I run the jquery against what I call the TR name - which is "dynamic_row".  For each of the dynamic rows, I call the TR the actual product name, and I forgot to call the PHP array as options on the blur.  Dumb, dumb.  I'm sorry to have wasted your time.

Comment: haha happens to all of us. don't worry about wasting other's time; this site is full of people happy to help. ;)